# Using useContext with React Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

My goal is to have a trackList variable in my Host.js file which is initially set to an empty list but can be updated using setTrackList. Even after closing this page and reopening, I do not want the list to be reset. I was advised to try to pass a state using contexts from a parent to a child function. I am currently getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_context' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "./Screens/Home";
import Host from "./Screens/Host";
import Join from "./Screens/Join";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export const HostContext = createContext(null)
export default function App() {

  const [trackList, setTrackList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <HostContext.Provider value={{trackList, setTrackList}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Host" component={Host} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Join" component={Join} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </HostContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Host.js

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {
  createRoom,
  destroyRoom,
  setTrackListener,
} from "../Firebase";
import getAuthAccessToken from "../AuthToken";
import { HostContext } from "../App.js"

let authToken = "";
let roomID = "";

export default function Host({ navigation }) {
  const { trackList, setTrackList } = useContext(HostContext)
  if (roomID == "") {
    roomID = createRoom();
  }
  if (authToken == "") {
    getAuthAccessToken().then((t) => (authToken = t));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrackListener(roomID, (t) => {
      if (t != null) {
        console.log(t.name);
        const newArray = [...trackList, t.name];
        setTrackList(newArray);
      }
    })
  }, []);
    

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Hosting {roomID}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={trackList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    color: "#590",
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Comment: Please add the `HostContext` code

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the correct context? I see you're passing tracklist as a variable to UserContext's provider but you're also trying to access tracklist through HostContext.

Note that when the way you're passing tracklist, you're only passing the variable, not the entire useState array. I prefer to pass variables down in an object. value={{tracklist, setTracklist}}

Comment: I have updated my code to only use ```Host Context``` and follow some of @zackrypaul advice. However, calling setTrackList in Host.js is not actually updating the value of trackList.

Comment: @AdrianRusso use `useEffect` hook where you set `setTrackListener`, and you can remove `existsTrackListener` it's redundant. `useEffect(() => {}, [])`

Comment: @user16967562 Thanks for this, makes sense. ```setTrackList``` unfortunately is still not updating ```trackList```. I've updated my code.

Comment: `console.log` value of `newArray`

Comment: When I do something like

```console.log(trackList); const newArray = [...trackList, t.name]; console.log(newArray); setTrackList(newArray); console.log(trackList)```

I get

```[]["test"][]```